# Add a space between every other character to display values, like MAC addresses, IPv6, and Hex?

Tags: regex, string, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a string

```
"AABBCCDDEEF0011223344556677889900"
```

I want to add a space between every other character such that my output is as follows:

```
"AA BB CC DD EE FF 00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 00"
```

I need to do this to a variable in a windows batch file:

```
set HEX=AABBCCDDEEF0011223344556677889900
<-- YOUR CODE -->
echo %HEX%

//outputs AA BB CC DD EE FF 00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 00
```

Comment: Do you know how long the string is?

Comment: `for /f "tokens=*" %%H in ('powershell -command "'%HEX%' -replace '(?<=\G..)(?=.)', ' '"') do set HEX=%%H`

Comment: @PetSerAl - Good idea. Probably should use `-NoProfile` on the PowerShell invocation.

Comment: @lit It definitely will not harm here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this sample script?

In this sample, after it retrieves 2 characters from the first character of `HEX`, the 2 characters are removed from `HEX`. This is repeated until the end of `HEX`.

#### Sample script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "HEX=AABBCCDDEEFF0011223344556677889900"
:LOOP
IF NOT "%HEX%"=="" (
  SET "RES=%RES%%HEX:~0,2% "
  SET "HEX=%HEX:~2%"
  GOTO :LOOP
)
ECHO "%RES:~0,-1%"
```

#### Result:

```
"AA BB CC DD EE FF 00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 00"
```

#### Note:

There is `"AABBCCDDEEF0011223344556677889900"` in question. It has only one `F`. But `"AA BB CC DD EE FF 00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 00"` is what you want. There is `FF` in expected result. So in my sample script, I used `SET "HEX=AABBCCDDEEFF0011223344556677889900"`.

If this is not useful for you, I'm sorry.

### Edit:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "HEX=AABBCCDDEEFF0011223344556677889900"
:LOOP
SET "RES=%RES%%HEX:~0,2% "
SET "HEX=%HEX:~2%"
IF DEFINED HEX GOTO LOOP
ECHO "%RES:~0,-1%"
```

From @Magoo's advice, the sample script was updated. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you simply have the two `set` commands in the loop, then `if defined hex goto loop` is easier. `if defined` is true if the variable has any value. Naturally, `if not defined` is also available. Using this structure, you can eliminate the parentheses.

Comment: @Magoo Thank you so much for your advice. I could study from your advice and this question. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless". In this case, your code as posted adds a terminal space on the line, but that space is invisible. Some people retype rather than copy/paste, so it's common practice on SO to use this form for string-assignment. You'll find many tips with the examples and solutions posted here on SO.

Comment: @Magoo Thank you so much for your advice again. I can get a lot of experiences today. Your advice will make me grow.

Answer (score 1):

I was fairly certain that this had been asked and answered before but unfortunately I cannot find it.

Here's an alternative pure batch file alternative:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "HEX=AABBCCDDEEF0011223344556677889900"

Set "_i=0"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('CMD/U/CEcho^=%HEX%^|Find /V ""') Do (
    Set/A "_i+=1, _m=_i%%2"
    If !_m! Equ 0 (Set "_s=!_s!%%A ") Else Set "_s=!_s!%%A")
If %_m% Equ 0 Set "_s=%_s:~,-1%"
Echo=%_s%

Timeout -1
```

…and one leveraging powershell:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "HEX=AABBCCDDEEF0011223344556677889900"

Set "PAIRS="
For /F %%A In ('PowerShell -C "'%HEX%' -Split '(..)'|?{$_}"') Do Set "PAIRS=!PAIRS! %%A"
Echo %PAIRS:~1%

Timeout -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short and fast pure batch solution that avoids any GOTO loop

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "hex=AABBCCDDEEFF0011223344556677889900"

set "out="
for /l %%N in (0,2,8191) do if "!hex:~%%N!" equ "" (goto :done) else set "out=!out!!hex:~%%N,2! "
:done
set "hex=!out:~0,-1!"
echo [!hex!]
```

And here is the same logic as a callable function:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "hex=AABBCCDDEEFF0011223344556677889900"

:: Simply print the result
call :formatHex hex

:: Store the result back in hex
call :formatHex hex hex
echo [%hex%]
exit /b


:formatHex  InVar  [OutVar]
:: Add space between hex pairs found in variable InVar.
:: Store the result in OutVar.
:: If OutVar is not specified, then ECHO the result
::
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "in=.!%~1!"  In case InVar is undefined, add a character in the front and start the loop at 1 instead of 0
set "out="
for /l %%N in (1,2,8191) do if "!in:~%%N!" equ "" (goto :done) else set "out=!out!!in:~%%N,2! "
:done
if defined out set "out=!out:~0,-1!"
endlocal & if "%~2" equ "" (echo(%out%) else set "%~2=%out%"
exit /b
```

If you have [JREPL.BAT - a hybrid JScript/batch regular expression text processing utility](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044), then you can simply use:

```
call jrepl "..(?=.)" "$& " /m /s hex /rtn hex
```

But the JREPL solution will be slower due to the startup time of the CSCRIPT engine.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly inappropriate question using inappropriate technology.

```
Set TempStr=AABBCCDDEEF0011223344556677889900
Set Str=%tempstr:~0,2% %tempstr:~2,2% %tempstr:~4,2% %tempstr:~6,2% [et al]
Echo %Str%
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of post a fairly inappropriate answer...

Comment: What's inappropriate. It answers the question in three lines, compare to the other silly answers. It is **also readable** so intent is clear.

Comment: This is totally impractical (unacceptable) because you must know the length of the string ahead of time, and it requires a hell-of-a-lot of typing for long strings.

Comment: @dbenham The question gave a specific string. 2 x 32 bit + 1 null.

Answer (score 0):

with pure batch (it should be fast as it not relies on labels to emulate loops , but calculates the script length and uses `for /l` loop):

```
@echo off

:::::::::: tests ::::::::::
call :funct aabb0103 hex
echo %hex%

call :funct AAFFEE00

exit /b %errorlevel%
::::::::::::::::::::::::


:funct
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 


set "str=%~1"
set LF=^


rem ** Two empty lines are required
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"
set $strLen=for /L %%n in (1 1 2) do if %%n==2 (%\n%
      for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%1 in ("!argv!") do (%\n%
         set "str=A!%%~2!"%\n%
           set "len=0"%\n%
           for /l %%A in (12,-1,0) do (%\n%
             set /a "len|=1<<%%A"%\n%
             for %%B in (!len!) do if "!str:~%%B,1!"=="" set /a "len&=~1<<%%A"%\n%
           )%\n%
           for %%v in (!len!) do endlocal^&if "%%~b" neq "" (set "%%~1=%%v") else echo %%v%\n%
      ) %\n%
) ELSE setlocal enableDelayedExpansion ^& set argv=,



%$strlen% strlen,str
set "res="
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%i in (0,1,%strlen%) do (
    set /a check=%%i %% 2
    if !check! == 0 if "!str:~%%i,1!" neq "" (
        set "res=!res!!str:~%%i,1!"
    )
    if !check! == 1 if "!str:~%%i,1!" neq "" (
        set "res=!res!!str:~%%i,1! "
    )
)


endlocal & endlocal & endlocal & if "%~2" NEQ "" (
    set "%~2=%res%"
) else (
    echo %res%
)
exit /b 0
```

JSCript hybrid - you can call it as a separate `.bat` file.The only argument it takes is the hex string:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
@echo off

cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"  %*

exit /b %errorlevel%
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

var hex=WScript.Arguments.Item(0);
var res="";

for ( var i = 0; i < hex.length; ++i){
    if(( i % 2)==0) {   
        res+=hex.charAt(i);
    } else {

        res+=hex.charAt(i)+' ';
    }
}

WScript.Echo(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it in PowerShell. Using an additional space character overcomes the problem of an odd number of characters in the string.

```
PS C:\src\t> $ss = 'AABBCCDDEEFF0011223344556677889900'
PS C:\src\t> $v = for ($i=0; $i -lt $ss.Length; $i += 2) { ($ss + ' ').Substring($i,2) }
PS C:\src\t> $v -join(' ')
AA BB CC DD EE FF 00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 00
```

If you must do it in cmd.exe:

```
C:>powershell -NoProfile -Command "$ss = 'AABBCCDDEEFF0011223344556677889900'; $v = for ($i=0; $i -lt $ss.Length; $i += 2) { ($ss + ' ').Substring($i,2) }; $v -join(' ')"
AA BB CC DD EE FF 00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 00
```

Or, using a variable:

```
C:>SET "SS=AABBCCDDEEFF0011223344556677889900"
C:>powershell -NoProfile -Command "$ss = '%SS%'; $v = for ($i=0; $i -lt $ss.Length; $i += 2) { ($ss + ' ').Substring($i,2) }; $v -join(' ')"
AA BB CC DD EE FF 00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 00
```